# Where should I put the business logic with a tornado/mongoengine app?

Tags: python, model-view-controller, tornado, mongoengine, object-relational-model

I'm writing a Tornado Rest API and I'm using mongoengine as an ODM.  I would like to keep things as decoupled as possible.  The reason I dont want my code right in the handler is I would like to make some functions async.

Would this be the best way to do this?:
     (Just psuedocode)

```
class UserSearchHandler(BaseHandler):

   @tornado.web.asynchronous
   @gen.coroutine
   def get(self):
     q = self.get_argument("query",strip=True)
     results = yield gen.Task(Node.search,q)
     self.write(results)
```

Inside Mongoengine

```
  class User(Docuement):
     first_name = StringField(max_length=50)
     last_name = StringField(max_length=50)

     @async
     def search(q,callback=None):
         if callback != None:
            return callback(User.objects(..magic))
         return User.objects(....)
         ...return some search query as json
```

Does it make sense to add member functions to an ODM?

Comment: Never tried it - but I'd like to hear about how that goes for you!